# Data mining textbook

Tags: data-mining

If you followed a DM course, which textbook was used?

I know about [Data Mining: Practical Machine Learning Tools and Techniques (Second Edition)](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~ml/weka/book.html) and [this poll](http://www.kdnuggets.com/polls/2005/data_mining_textbooks.htm). What did you effectively use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have been pretty happy with [Introduction to Data Mining](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~kumar/dmbook/index.php) by Tan et. al.

Now, I did not actually read it as part of a course, and I have only read the two chapters concerning association rule mining. Three sample chapters are available on the book's homepage, so why not take a look and see if you like it?

[Amazon link goes here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321321367) - allowing Jeff and Joel to make some profit on my answer :-)

Comment: Seconded.  We are using this book in my course.  It is very readable and the exercises for each chapter are non-trivial.  Definitely recommend it!